# Se puede modificar el font del título de la aplicación en android?

Tags: java, android

Es posible cambiar la fuente del texto en el título de la aplicación o ingresar alguna imagen pequeña para darle un estilo distinto del que viene cuando uno programa una aplicación?... (algo así como Instagram y su fuente de letra distinta al resto).

[image: A esta parte me refiero...]

Desde ya, muchas gracias por su tiempo. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Esto te serviria http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2013/03/styling-the-android-action-bar-with-a-custom-font/?

Comment: @LombardaArda el enlace que compartes es para el ActionBar...

Comment: @Jorgesys puedes adaptarlo al titulo de la actividad, en el metodo `onCreate` pones `setTitle` y listo. Se lo he pasado como ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu aplicación tiene configurada como  minima API 16, (minSdkVersion 16) puedes realizar este método.

Teniendo tu fuente definida dentro del directorio `/font`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de tu archivo `styles.xml` puedes definir a el estilo que use tu aplicación o `Activity` la fuente, por ejemplo:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/jorgesys_font</item>
</style>
```

Para obtener el titulo con otro tipo de fuente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **CP 301 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.